# Update JSON object MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I want to update a JSON object in MySQL.

**TABLE**

```
id (int-11, not_null, auto_inc)
labels (json)
```

**JSON Beautify**

```
[
  {
    "tagname": "FOO",
    "category": "CAT_1",
    "isnew": "no",
    "isdeleted": "no"
  },
  {
    "tagname": "BAR",
    "category": "CAT_2",
    "isnew": "yes",
    "isdeleted": "no"
  }
]
```

**I want to add a new TAG element (JSON OBJECT) next to the existing objects, but without SELECTing first the field and updating all the field with text**.
I have Google a lot but I can not understand yet the MySQL's JSON treatment. I have just learned how to insert data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(
    `id` ,
    `labels` 
)
VALUES(
    null ,
    JSON_ARRAY
    (
        JSON_OBJECT
        (
            "tagname", "FOO",
            "category", "CAT_1",
            "isnew", "no",
            "isdeleted", "no"
        ),
        JSON_OBJECT
        (
            "tagname", "BAR",
            "category", "CAT_2",
            "isnew", "yes",
            "isdeleted", "no"
        )

    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [JSON_ARRAY_APPEND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append):

```
UPDATE tab
SET labels = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(labels, '$', 
     JSON_OBJECT
        (
            "tagname", "BARX",
            "category", "CAT_3",
            "isnew", "yes",
            "isdeleted", "no"
        )                         
 )
WHERE ID = 1;
```

**[DB-Fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kg9N7AntF3AAonurSsbBHw/0)**